# Fetch only email values from serialised array

Tags: php, wordpress

```
0 => s:94:"a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}";
```

Can anyone help to fetch only email values from this array?

I tried:

```
global $post;
$post = $wp_query->post;
$id = $post->ID;

$custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['offer'];

foreach ($my_custom_field as $key => $value) {
  echo $key['email'] . " => " . $value['email'] . "<br />";
}
```

and getting output `s`.

I also tried:

```
$data = 'a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}';
$value = array_pop(explode(':', $data[0], 0));
echo $value;
```

but the output still remains `s`.

Can anyone help to fetch only email value?

**Updating more details:**

How data is getting inserted:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_offer'])){
    global $post;
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    $offer_details =  array(
                      'name' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['name']),
                        'email' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['email']),
                         'message' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['message_content'])
                    );
    // the rest of your code, inserting metadata
    $check = add_post_meta( $id, 'offer', serialize($offer_details) );
}
   if($check){esc_html_e( 'Offer Submitted.', 'ivproperty' );}
```

Complete data stored in **$custom_fields:**

```
property_status: Sold, Property_ID: lorem ipsum, Available_From: lorem ipsum, Year_Built: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Material: lorem ipsum, Structure_Type: lorem ipsum, AC: lorem ipsum, Acres: lorem ipsum, Bedroom_Features: lorem ipsum, Cross_Streets: lorem ipsum, Dining_Area: lorem ipsum, Disability_Access: lorem ipsum, Entry_Location: lorem ipsum, Exterior_Cnstruction: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Fuel: lorem ipsum, Fireplace_Location: lorem ipsum, Legal_Desc: lorem ipsum, Lot_Description: lorem ipsum, Lot_Size_Source: lorem ipsum, Misc_Interior: lorem ipsum, Sewer: lorem ipsum, Source_Of_Sqft: lorem ipsum, Terms: lorem ipsum, View_Desc: lorem ipsum, address: 129-133 West 22nd Street, local-area: Shoreditch, latitude: 40.7427704, longitude: -73.99455039999998, city: Bretagne, postcode: 10011, country: USA, phone: 212245-4606, fax: 212245-4606, contact-email: test@test.com, contact_web: e-plugin.com, listing_contact_source: new_value, youtube: 0y4rXoWrJlw, facebook: test, linkedin: test, twitter: test, instagram: test, youtube_social: test, bedrooms: 4, bathrooms: 3, guest: 1, garages: 2, sale_or_rent_price: 5210641, price_postfix_text: $, area: 6000, area_postfix_text: SFT, rent_period: , _favorites: , , 1, _edit_lock: 1632717839:1, _edit_last: 1, _public_facilities: a:3:{s:4:"Shop";s:0:"";s:7:"Airport";s:1:"8";s:11:"City center";s:1:"4";}, state: , image_gallery_ids: ,4290,4289, contact_name: , vimeo: , rs_page_bg_color: , site-sidebar-layout: default, site-content-layout: default, theme-transparent-header-meta: default, stick-header-meta: default, realpro_featured: featured, offer: s:94:"a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}";, _plan_description_0:
```

Comment: Why not just `unserialize` this array and iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of overcomplicating things by trying to manually extract the value you want, just unserialize the string and you'll get a perfectly ordinary PHP array.

```
$data = 'a:3:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Sanad Qazi";s:5:"email";s:14:"test@sanad.com";s:7:"message";s:4:"test";}';

$email = unserialize($data)['email'];
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/V0Eiv

Comment: Hi, thanks for code but as I tried, nothing is getting is printed; can you please check what's wrong: 
`global $post;  $post = $wp_query->post;  $id = $post->ID;  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($id);   $email = unserialize($custom_fields)['email'];    echo $email;`

Comment: @Sanad - Without knowing the _exact_ contents of `$custom_fields` (your question doesn't make that clear), I can't tell you what the issue is.

Comment: I added more data as you mentioned in comments, can you please help me to fix it now?